# Como remover apenas os itens selecionados de uma lista ToDo?

Tags: react, input, checkbox

Eu estou criando uma lista "To Do" em react, e estou buscando um meio de remover apenas os itens com o input selecionados. tem como fazer isso?
segue uns pedaços do código.
Detalhe, o id do input está ligado a um "date.Now".

```
const ClearDone = () => {
    if ("input selecionado") {
      "limpar a que está com o imput selecionado."
    }
  };

<button onClick={() => ClearDone()}>Limpar Concluidas</S.Botao>

{lista.map((item) => (
            <div>
              <div>
                <input id={item.id} type="checkbox" />
                <label for={item.id}>{item.tarefas}</label>
                <button onClick={() => Delete(item.id)}>X</button>
              </div>
              <hr />
            </div>
          ))}
```

Answer (score 2):

1- coloca o lista dentro de um useState depois seta um novo valor dela quando for chamada a função Delete actualizando o estado da da lista para lista filtrada

```
const [lista, setLista] = useState<any>([])

function Delete(id) {
   const newList = lista.filter((item) => item !== id)
   setLista(newList)
}

{lista.map((item) => (
            <div>
              <div>
                <input id={item.id} type="checkbox" />
                <label for={item.id}>{item.tarefas}</label>
                <button onClick={() => Delete(item.id)}>X</button>
              </div>
              <hr />
            </div>
          ))}
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).